# How to Learn MS SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I would like to start learning SQL Server 2005 on my own.  Can anyone recommend good books or websites that will be a good start for me?

Comment: Is there a reason for having that version as opposed to say MS SQL Server 2008 or whatever new MS SQL Server is being developed now?

Comment: Just the version my company has. we may get 2008 in the future but as of now they have decided to stick with 05

Comment: **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Thus I flagged this question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Books:**

[Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2005: T-SQL Querying](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623139)

[Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2005: The Storage Engine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621055)

[Pro SQL Server 2005 Database Design and Optimization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590595297)

**Sites:**

[SQL Server Programming Hacks](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/SQL_Server_Programming_Hacks_-_100%2B_List)

[sqlserverpedia](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Main_Page)

[Microsoft SQL Server 2005 – Learning Portal](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/2005/sql/default.mspx)

[Good SQL Articles To Read If You Can't Afford Books](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/good-sql-articles-to-read-if-you-can-t-a)

Comment: Thank you very much.  no drought of info here.

Answer (score 1):

Are you learning SQL from scratch?

I would suggest starting with this [SQL Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp).

However if you know SQL already then [this is a good list of tutorials on SQL 2005 features](http://www.intelligentedu.com/blogs/post/best_new_training_sites/3662/102-sql-server-2005-tutorials-and-articles).

Comment: I know the basics of sql not much else.  Thank you for your recomendations also

Answer (score 1):

If you want to gain an good understanding of SQL Server end-to-end, I have found Robert Vieira's books on SQL Server to be useful.

Here is [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764584340) I recommend.

It is a good book and I recommend it for assimilating the theory.

If you need a good reference book I have found that Murach's books on SQL server to be useful.

Here is [one](http://www.murach.com/books/sql5/index.htm) I recommend.

This a good book for quick "cook book" type solutions.

Comment: Titles would be nice, one of your links are dead...

Answer (score 1):

here is an additional link for those common questions

[The Ten Most Asked SQL Server Questions And Their Answers](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/the-ten-most-asked-sql-server-questions--1)

Answer (score 1):

For heavier TSQL questions, I found this blog useful :

http://www.sommarskog.se/

Answer (score 1):

[Learning SQL on SQL Server 2005](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596102151) is a good book for beginners. It covers SQL syntax and server administration tasks.