# best database book for developers

Tags: database

I want to download a good database book for developers, can you guide me and send me good links to find a good one. I am working with SQL Server 2008.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a good book to learn SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982/looking-for-a-good-book-to-learn-sql)

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. Before you ask a new question it's worth searching stackoverflow (using the edit box at the top right of the screen), for example [http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=book+sql+2008](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=book+sql+2008).

Answer (score 12):

This has been asked here many times before:

- [A beginner's guide to SQL database design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377375/a-beginners-guide-to-sql-database-design)
- [Can anyone recommend a book for building enterprise database applications in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641798/can-anyone-recommend-a-book-for-building-enterprise-database-applications-in-net)

My personal favorite resource is [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx) - this is the documentation that comes with SQL server.

Comment: Most of these links don't work

Answer (score 3):

For database concepts [Fundamentals of Database Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321122267)

Good Books for SQL [Looking for a good book to learn SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982/looking-for-a-good-book-to-learn-sql)

For SQl Server [How to Learn MS SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443942/how-to-learn-ms-sql-server-2005)

[Beginning SQL Server 2005 Administration](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470047046)

FOr MySql [What are the best books for MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430564/what-the-best-book-for-mysql)

[Book recommendation for advanced SQL design, scripting and optimiziation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343709/book-recommendation-for-advanced-sql-design-scripting-and-optimiziation)

[What are some resources I can use to learn profiling/optimizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550109/what-are-some-resources-i-can-use-to-learn-profiling-optimizing/)

Comment: the links are broken

Answer (score 2):

Funny that no one seems to mention [Date's "SQL and relational theory : How to write accurate SQL code".](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596523068)

Answer (score 1):

[Head First SQL](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfsql/) (O'Reilly) is excellent, whole series is great.

They start of with the basics (as do most books), covering syntax, database design and advanced querying.

Excrept:

> 2008 Jolt Productivity Award Winner!
>
> Is your data dragging you down? Are your tables all tangled up? Well
>   we've got the tools to teach you just how to wrangle your databases
>   into submission. Using the latest research in neurobiology, cognitive
>   science, and learning theory to craft a multi-sensory SQL learning
>   experience, Head First SQL has a visually rich format designed for the
>   way your brain works, not a text-heavy approach that puts you to
>   sleep.
>
> Maybe you've written some simple SQL queries to interact with
>   databases. But now you want more, you want to really dig into those
>   databases and work with your data. Head First SQL will show you the
>   fundamentals of SQL and how to really take advantage of it. We'll take
>   you on a journey through the language, from basic INSERT statements
>   and SELECT queries to hardcore database manipulation with indices,
>   joins, and transactions. We all know "Data is Power"—but we'll show
>   you how to have "Power over your Data". Expect to have fun, expect to
>   learn, and expect to be querying, normalizing, and joining your data
>   like a pro by the time you're finished reading!

Comment: i want a book to teaches me, but not in the basic levels.

Answer (score 0):

See Kalen Delaney's [recommended reading list](https://docs.google.com/Doc?id=d4nxnt7_3f7ngptdh). There's some great books listed there, as well as other resources.

Answer (score -2):

May I recommend

[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Unleashed](http://best-gear.org/microsoft-sql-server-r2-unleashed-2008/)

Comment: Link only answers are not really welcome here - please add at least a summary of the link!